# How to share aggregated state of one dataframe to another dataframe?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have two dataframes `df1` and `df2`

I want to filter `df2` based on some aggregated result of `df1`

For example

```scala
val resultDf1 = df1
    .filter(// some filter logic)
val aggDf1 = resultDf1.agg(min("A"), max("A"))


df2
    .filter(col("myColumn") > aggDf1.getInt(0))
    .filter(col("myColumn") < aggDf1.getInt(1))
```

What is the canonical way in spark to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can collect the min/max values to the driver and use them in the second query, for example:

```scala
val aggDf1 = resultDf1.agg(min("A"), max("A"))
val (minValue, maxValue) = aggDf1.as[(Int, Int)].first

df2.filter(col("myColumn") > minValue && col("myColumn") < maxValue)
```

Comment: Where is collect happening in this case? when calling `.first` ?

Comment: `first` collects the first row of the dataframe

Comment: Whats the advantage of collecting to driver vs broadcast?

Comment: When you want to avoid distribution of a variable per partition instead of per node. For example, a big array that is used as part of the tranformation will be shipped to each partition unless it is broadcasted and then it is shipped once per node.